# Why is my remote control not opening my garage door?

Tags: garage-door-opener, garage-door

I'm having garage door issues. My opener model is a Genie H6000A, the following symptoms are happening:

- Garage door opens/closes fine when the wall button is pressed and hold.
- Garage door closes fine when remote control is pressed.
- PROBLEM: Garage door will only open about ~10 inches when remote control button is pressed.

I will appreciate any ideas or suggestions.

TIA, Angel.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Is this a change from its previous behavior? If so, when did it start? Do you have to hold the wall button down for the garage door to open/close?

Comment: What model garage door opener?  And what happens if you just press the button once, and don't hold, when trying to close the door using the wall button?

Comment: @DanielGriscom It's been like that since I bought the house one year ago. And yes, I have to hold the wall button down for the garage door to open/close.

Comment: If you release the door from the opener by pulling on the cord release, how hard is it to raise the door manually?

Comment: @JimStewart I tried that yesterday. I was able to lift it without too much effort. I'm thinking I need to increase the up force.

Comment: If you were able to lift the door without too much effort, then I would say the spring tension is about right and you should look elsewhere for the source of your problem. It may be the sensors that tell the motor to stop running at the ends of travel are out of adjustment. There are a number of possible faults and it may be best to call a garage door repair service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed the problem by increasing the up-open-force 1/4 knob turn in the motor. Now it works like a champ :)

Answer (score 1):

The fact that you have to hold down the indoor button to keep the garage door moving strongly suggests that the controller is detecting a problem. The fact that the problem only happen when going up strongly suggests that it's the opening tension which is mis-set. Get the manual and see what you can find out; it probably spells out handling just such an occurrence.